# JQuery with IE reading inherted css property, how to prevent?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, text-align

I have an issue with internet explorer dealing with JQuery or JQuery dealing with IE :)

Simply I have the following code:

```
$(function () {
   $("*").each(function (i) {
    var textalign = $(this).css("text-align");
    if (textalign == "left") {$(this).css({'text-align': 'right'});} 
      else if (textalign == "right"){$(this).css({'text-align': 'left'});}
   });
});
```

The function of code is to swap text-align of all tags, in FF & Chrome this code do perfect work, but on IE I have a problem on it, I think it read inherited text-align property after changing parent property and swap it again !

To Understand what happening, i attached here 2 images of source code after applying JQuery code:

In FF (Perfect !) : [image: Firefox result's source code snapshot]

In IE (Wrongly !) : [image: IE result's source code snapshot]

BTW, if you wondering about use this way, I have Open Source project and using inline styling on hundreds of JSPs, with tables too, so Its workaround solution to flip layout and support multilingual product (support ltr & rtl languages) ...

Hopefully found solution.

Note: I'm using JQuery 1.7.1 ... and this problem issued in ie8 & ie9.

Note 2: I got worst results when using `jQuery("*").each(jQuery("*").get().reverse(), function (i) {` or `jQuery(jQuery("*").get().reverse()).each(function (i) {`

**Edit 1 & 2: was inside this question**

**Edit 3:**

Note 3 : the issue is happening with all elements on page whatever that element even `script` , `html` , `style` , ... etc and strangest thing some of elements did not get any touch ! see this screenshot:
[image: all elements but some too !]

**Edit 4:**

My problem partially solved, on IE9 working well, in IE8 not working, solution from [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836859/jquery-with-ie-reading-inherted-css-property-how-to-prevent/8298786#8298786) , after trying alot of ways the summery on my code:

in JQuery code:

```
if (jQuery.browser.msie == false || jQuery.browser.msie == undefined) { 
            if (textalign == "left") {jQuery(this).css({'text-align': 'right'});} 
            else if (textalign == "right"){jQuery(this).css({'text-align': 'left'});}
        }
```

In CSS file that loaded for IE only :

```
body *[style*="text-align: left"] {
  text-align: right !important;
}

body *[style*="text-align: right"] {
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

Regards,

Comment: some people may label you crazy for this, but here is a link that can help you m8 http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/right-to-left.html,

Comment: better still, you should use css for this, and use the child inheriting using the greater and less than , `#selector ">" p{text-align:right;}`

Comment: @Val thanks , but rtl didn't solve the problem, yes that made almost all the work, but the problem is with "inline" style with "text-align" if that used classes that should be better to solve!, but its not !

Comment: ur problem is using inlines, it's a bad practice. use display:block combined with float:left/right so every divider is a block and not inline and it's alot easier to manage, with just margin, and padding...

Comment: btw that link is design especially for arabic language, and other languages which write right-to-left and it's what you should do, and easy to switch between the two.

Comment: Val seems you didn't understand my problem, I have open source product, actually its Alfresco Explorer, i want to modify it to support multilingual layout, if you check source code you will see that wrote styles as "inline" method styling wrote with the code not in external file.

that link that what i made  before, and my problem is after that !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn´t this be of any help?

```
body.rtl * {
  text-align: right !important;
}
```

You really should mark the elements that should keep the rule for `text-align: left` with a specific CSS class to separate them from the rest.

You may also try this CSS to switch text-align values

```
body *[style*="text-align: left"] {
  text-align: right !important;
}

body *[style*="text-align: right"] {
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

I´ve not tested this one yet but it should make all elements with a style attribute value containing "text-align: left" to use that rule.

**UPDATE**

Created an example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ta3vB/1/). Hope it helps.

**UPDATE 2**

New solution using jQuery: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NPLE4/1/)

```
$('body *[style*="text-align"]').each(function() {

    // Toggle text-align value
    $(this).css('text-align', (($(this).css('text-align') == 'left') ? 'right' : 'left'));

});
```

Comment: No, because I'm using text-align: left fro some element style, like textboxes, thanks for try.

Comment: CSS rules tagged with !important overrides inline rules and it should work.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but what if I'm using `text-aling: left` in somewhere? that is exactly why I made swapping code ! if element has right turn it to left and vice versa. I want to swap not to make all align to right.

Comment: Are you saying that all elements with the inline rule text-align: left should keep their style or are we just talking about a few of them? Updating my answer.

Comment: I have mixed elements, some of them left and another right, I want to make right to left and left one to right, so I can't make all left or all to right.

Comment: Ok, but aren´t there elements that should always stay the same?

Comment: just about your new updated solution, just like not working ! , I think it will be helpful if work !

Comment: Updated my answer with a new solution using jQuery.

Comment: nothing applied, nothing changed, like you don't do anything, and I didn't get any errors ! , btw I'm using `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8"/>`

Comment: look into my Edit 4 on question, note that css hack only working in IE9, not working in IE8 or Firefox, so that why I still using my code with pretty changes.

Answer (score 1):

Why not circumvent the problem by performing your loop in reverse?

Replace this:

```
$("*").each(function (i) {
```

With this:

```
$.each($("*").get().reverse(), function (i) {
```

Comment: Thanks, seems that shall be helpful, I'll try it, but before that is that way make performance slower !??

Comment: the $("*") which goes through every single element on the page

Answer (score 0):

This is a really interesting problem. Essentially, it sounds like you want to select parts of the DOM that can contain content (`<p>`, `<div>`, `<span>`, etc.) while excluding all other elements.

It *sounds* like the jQuery psuedo-selector `$(":visible")` would work for you, but considering that IE assigned this value to completely invalid elements, I have my doubts.

It may be crazy, but perhaps you should consider coming up with a list content-level DOM elements for which `style="text-align: right"` is valid. This could be a really tall task, depending on the age of the product and what sort of HTML it generates. If you're dealing with a set of ten or twelve elements, it might be worth writing a style sheet to handle this and loading that via jQuery (assuming you can't easily include it on all your pages).